# iphone can't see alternative content

Tags: iphone, html, flash, ios

```
<object width="300" height="100" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
    <param value="5352f5c8e96c251fb9d79890f2294608.swf" name="movie">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object width="300" height="100" data="5352f5c8e96c251fb9d79890f2294608.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <a id="alternative" target="_blank" href="#">iphone can't see me</a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

iphone safari can't see `<a id="alternative" target="_blank" href="#">iphone can't see me</a>`

But PC's safari,firefox can see the alternative. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your alternate content is hidden from the iPhone, is because iOS does not support Flash. When Safari Mobile sees your object tag, it skips it and therefore will not see the alternate content inside of it.

You should look into using JavaScript, or a javascript library (SWFObject, for example) to show your flash player on your webpage so that you can detect when Flash is unavailable and serve alternate content when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Um, first of all: iPhone's don't support flash. Only through jailbreaking can you enable flash.